# java :OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: java, nio, apache-nifi

I want to  lock   file and  then make  some   updates    on it   but  every  time  i  want to make this   operation  i  got  :java.nio.channels.overlappingFilelockException,  i  tried  to  add catch  clause  with  this  exception with this   peace  of  code:

```
catch(OverlappingFilelockException e){
lock.relese();
}
```

but  this doesn't  work   for me. here is  my   java code , what should i  do   to get  rid  of  this  exception?

```
     File file = new File("C://Users//user//Desktop//conf1.xml");
        String content = '';
        BufferedReader s;
        BufferedWriter w;
        RandomAccessFile  ini=new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");;
        FileLock lock= ini.getChannel().tryLock();;
        def flowFile1=session.create();

        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
        Document  doc=null;
        String start, startDate, endDate, runAs, makeVersion, patch;
        try {

            String sCurrentLine;
            s = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));


            while ((sCurrentLine = s.readLine()) != null) {
                content += sCurrentLine;
            }
            ini.seek(0);




            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(bos);
            try {
                transformer.transform(source, result1);
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
            String data = bos.toString();
            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                ini.setLength(0);
                w = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
                w.write(data);
                lock.release();
                w.close();



            }



        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {



            lock.release();
            ini.close();
        }
```

Comment: Please boil down your code to a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. I do not think that xml procession has something to do with java.nio errors.

Comment: 'This doesn't work for me' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
    lock.release();
}
```

What lock? You didn't get a lock. You got an exception. Instead of a lock. You don't even have the `lock` *variable*, because it isn't in scope.

Remove the `release()` line.

Comment: Do  you mean removing  lock.release()?

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

`OverlappingFilelockException` starts with uppercase letter. Your `catch` statement does not compile because the overlappingFilelockException (lowercase) is unknown. Correct it and your exception will be caught as expected.

A file lock exception is most likely thrown because some other process/thread holds a lock on the file. Find out who this can be, release the lock by the lock holder and try again.

Comment: It  isn't  the  case  i  have  uppercase  in my  original  code

Comment: It can't  prevent trowing excpetion

Comment: And which line gives you the exception?

Comment: I   have  closed  one more channel and  now   it  works   nice  :D